# How to make Test Method using job of another Test Method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Here is what am I doing :

```
private String connection = "";

[TestMethod]
public void Connect()
{
    Encrypter encrypter = new Encrypter("64bit");

    String keyword = encrypter.Decrypt("5465465465==");

    // Check if crypter is changed
    Assert.AreEqual(true, encrypter.SetCrypter("AES"));

    this.connection = encrypter.Decrypt
        ("65465465466", keyword);
}

[TestMethod]
public void NhibernateFluentTest()
{
    NHibernate.ISessionFactory session =
        Fluently.Configure().Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(this.connection)).BuildSessionFactory();

    Assert.IsNotNull(session);
}
```

"Connect" Test Method is changing connection string which is must be using in "NhibernateFluentTest" Test Method but it's just separate methods and second one can't see first one. How can I solve this trouble ?

Comment: What data your trying to share between the two methods? If one has to talk to another, then you have to call one in another.

Comment: @zenwalker I don't think it's possible in this way. They are test methods.

Comment: So what, you still can call 1 method from other method which is a testmethod. Just like if you have an private method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To setup a common state that is safe to reuse during your tests, create a Setup method using the appropriate attribute. In MSTest, I believe that is `[TestInitialize]`, but you'll be able to find it. There is a similar method to teardown the state. These methods will then run before and after each test.

Comment: In addition to this comment if you find yourself with the need to reuse code across tests I will typically create a single level of inheritance and in the SetUp attributed method place this common code

Answer (score 1):

*Tests should never depend on other tests*. If a test fails or succeeds depending on whether another test has been executed, it will be very hard to rely on test results.

I would suggest you refactor your code so that there is a method that prepares the string as needed for both tests, and call that method from them.